# PHP require a file from another directory: No such file or directory

Tags: php

My project structure:

```
/Controllers
/Models
index.php
```

From my index.php I include the controller and call a function from that controller: (it's in the root folder)

```
include 'Controllers/CategoriesController.php';
$content = CategoriesController::getCategories();
```

CategoriesController.php (which is in the controllers directory):

```
static function getCategories(){
    require '../Models/Database.php';
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    ...
```

Here i get an error in the require line:  require(../Models/Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...

Why? How can this error be resolved? Thanks!

Comment: try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: and how to refer through $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to '../Models/Database.php' ?

Comment: _“Why? ”_ - because your index.php script is _not_ running "inside" the `Controllers` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try absolute path instead relative path. Change the following

```
require '../Models/Database.php';
```

to

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Models/Database.php';
```

'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
    The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file. 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 4):

[As described on PHP's documentation regarding include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory **and the current working directory before failing.** The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

Thus, the `require` call in `Controllers/CategoriesController.php` will be relative to the folder containing the main script (`index.php`), explaining why you get this error message.

However, a magic variable, `__DIR__` is exposed by the interpreter and contains the full path to the current file. `__DIR__` exists starting from PHP 5.3 and has the same value than `dirname(__FILE__)`. Thus, calling `require` (or `include`) the following way will behave as you are expecting to:

```
require __DIR__ . '../Models/Database.php';
```

Comment: thank you very much! I have been working in frameworks every time and now had to implement a simple proj without any frameworks and I am not used to such kind of things :) Thank you very much!